# Data Type Mapping in ADO.NET

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ado.net

I'm using ADO.Net in PowerShell to read and update some rows from a table in SQL Server. I need to define some System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter parameters for the UpdateCommand of my SqlAdapter. I'm struggling with setting the parameters SqlDbType property.

I found the mapping between .NET and SQL data types on [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings). Do I need to write a function myself that does this mapping? I would have expected that would be handled automatically by ADO.Net.

Comment: Although ADO.NET can infer the parameter data type based on the provided .NET data type (e.g. using the `AddWithValue()` method), I suggest you specify the intended SQL data type and length to improve performance and avoid surprises. For example, strings in .NET are Unicode so parameters will be inferred as `nvarchar` even if the column is `varchar`. This can cause full table scans when the parameter is used in `WHERE` clauses even though the column may be indexed.

Comment: Thanks! In my case, every parameter is linked to a column in the table, either as part of the key or as the column to be updated. I will write a function that queries the SQL data type of the corresponding column with the DMVs and sets that type into the SqlDbType property. Do you think that would be a good solution?

Comment: That is one method. Another is with the `SqlConnection.GetSchema()`(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.getschema), although either should work.